# Approach for binding on a MVVM application using Portable Class Libraries

Tags: mvvm, portable-class-library

I'm trying to port the core of an application across to Portable Class Libraries and don't appear to have binding support.

I'm trying to bind a property on my ViewModel to my Model, which consists of an ObservableDictionary (`INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, IDictionary<string, string>`).  I do this usually (with WP7) by using the following code when initialising the view model:

`SetBinding(MyProperty, new Binding(string.Format("MyDictionary[{0}]", "thekey")) { Source = MyModel });`

How would I approach this when using Portable Class Libraries, where it seems like the Binding class is unavailable?

Comment: Are you using DataBinding between ViewModel and Model ? I'm sure the Binding class exists since it's used in XAML. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh563947.aspx)

Comment: I am yes, I need to databind from my ViewModel to an Observable IDictionary on the Model.  The article you link to doesn't describe my scenario.  I imagine I'll need to create a wrapper that hooks up to the INotifyCollectionChanged to update the ViewModel but that seems quite a messy approach seeing how simple using Binding was previously.

Comment: I think some code to better understand your scenario is needed.

Comment: It's nothing more complicated than binding a property on a view model to the model which is exposed using a dictionary that exposes NotifyCollectionChanged. I have included sample code which creates this binding when I was using a class derived from Control to handle this, but I think I'm going to have to do some manual wiring up to handle this, as I have neither a DependencyProperty or Binding, was hoping for something a bit smarter but there you go.

Comment: Frankly, this is new to me regarding typical MVVM pattern.

Comment: I admit it's not standard, but in this case my model is a collection of key value pairs, where the key I need to bind to isn't known until runtime. I think I've got a workable version, I'm just trying to add in some IValueConverter support as well, although I'll probably have to add in my own interface as it doesn't look like IValueConverter exists in PCL either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this by having the base class for the ViewModels wire up to the PropertyChanged event of the ViewModel and the NotifyCollectionChanged event of the ObservableDictionary.  I then have a method (with a set of overloads for additionally supplying an implementation of an IPclValueConverter which is a copy of the IValueConverter) which adds to a collection of PclBinding objects which is a set of PropertyInfo, dictionary key, IPclValueConverter and a converter parameter.

Within the PropertyChanged/NotifyCollectionChanged I check to see if the binding should be updated, and if so perform the update passing the value through a converter if present.

This means that from my original example, I now write the following inside my ViewModel which creates the binding as required:

`SetBinding(() => MyProperty, "theKey");`

If anyone is actually interested in this code I'd be happy to post it up. :)